Ideal Bike Shed Dimensions
I am building a bike shed for a family. We have at least 4 bikes (2 adults and 2 children) plus some little push bikes which may or may not go soon. I am thinking of hanging one on the ceiling/rafters, one on the wall and let the rest stand. The kids will grow up and get progressively bigger bikes so we need to accommodate 4 adult bikes really. I can do the dimensions for height and width. But what would you consider the best depth to include? I will also include some hooks and a shelf but I am hoping this will fit on the sides and in spare space, so I just need to be able to fit all 4 bikes in the minimum depth I can get away with without struggling.

As big as possible, really. What are your limits?

Something the size of a three car garage should almost be big enough. There's the storage you describe plus you are going to need space to work on bikes.

How much tetris are you willing to put up with to get some of the bikes out? i.e. Are you frequently switching which bike(s) you need, or is it okay to have 1-2 easily available and 2-3 less convenient?

Ask the question the other way around, and you get "I have X by Y space, how much do I have to leave at the property boundary or next to another wall?"    And all the rest will be workshop and bike storage.

Don't forget the N+1  factor. The value of N being the number of bikes you need plus one additional for want. As in, I have a commuter {N} but I want a gravel bike also, then a mountain bike and maybe an E Bike, etc,etc, toward infinity.

I have 10x12 foot (3.0x3.6 metre) shed with 6 bikes ready to ride, 2 hanging, and 3 vintage on the walls.
If I remove 2, I can work at the bench. Do over again? I’d go 12x12 foot or more.

Forgot my ‘ . If the 1970s effort had succeeded and it was meters I guess it would be an epic bike shop. If inches then a Lego set.

The most important thing with dimensioning a bike shed, is to remember that:

You need enough space to get in and get any bike out without a hassle.

Commuter bikes need to be accessed in a rather tired state in the dark morning every day. You don't want to disentangle handle bars and/or brake/shifter cables every day in this state.

On top of a bike having roughly the same outer dimensions as a motor bike (only much less mass), your bikes are likely to have or aquire some kind of basket for luggage over the years.

If you hang a bike, you must still have the open space available to get it down. You don't want to be playing musical bikes every morning!


So, considering that a bike is usually somewhere between 0.5m to 0.7m, and the same goes for a human that gets in, grabs a bike, and gets out again, I'd say you need at the absolute minimum a width of 4m to accomodate four bikes and two access aisles (that's 0.67m per bike and aisle). A length of 2.5m should be sufficient for most bikes. Once your shed is long enough for all your bikes, any additional length is next to useless. However, these numbers are for bike storage only. There no space for any additional stuff allocated in there. If you want to use a trailer, you need to plan a place for that as well. If you want to store tools, you need to plan places for them as well. If you try to make do with any less than these numbers, or allow other stuff to creep into your bike space, you will suffer for it.

Daily bikes need to be stored rubber down and without handlebars touching. The less the user's physical abilities are the easier it needs to be to store the bikes. This means that my kids bikes are closest to the door, with rear tyres pushed into slots on the wall so that they can just push the bike in backwards when the come and pull it out when they go. My bikes are stored between the kids' bikes with front wheel towards the wall because I am tall, patient and strong enough to fiddle with them when I go. This saves space because I don't need to leave space between the bikes for humans to operate them. You should put all your bikes in a row and measure them to get a better idea of the space you need.
I have bikes on rafters and walls. I haven't used one for four years now, because it's at the back corner... It's a very special bike to me.
The next best thing you can do is to fit a bike repair stand and a desk (with a vise and a drill press and an ultrasonic cleaner and a ...). Go as big as you can.

You should look into your local bicycle community for guidelines. The German Cyclists Association ADFC (Allgemeiner Deutscher Fahrrad Club) is providing those.
The PDF "Tips for the planning of
bicycle parking facilities" ("Hinweise für die Planung von
Fahrrad-Abstellanlagen") (https://www.adfc-bayern.de/fileadmin/user_upload/images/01_Menue_links/Service_Dienstleistungen/Abstellanlagen/ADFC_BY_Hinweise_Planung_Abstellanlagen_2018_12_web.pdf) defines a minimum of 70*190 cm per bicycle. This includes 5 cm of space between the handlebars. Behind the bikes, where you move your bike and yourself around, the space should be at least 180 cm in depth.

As you can see, there are several possibilities for parking your bicycles.
Getting bigger and more comfy from this minimum is this PDF "Information for architects and building owners for parking bicycles" ("Hinweise für Architekten und Bauherren
zum Abstellen von Fahrrädern") (https://www.agfs-nrw.de/fileadmin/Fachthemen/Parken-Abstellen/wo-steht-ihr-fahrrad/Handlungsleitfaden_Fahrradparken_RZ_Web.pdf). This document describes the minimal space per bike as 200*100 cm or 200*120 cm as comfortable.

Maybe someone can add there local recommendations to get a bigger picture.

Are these for shared bikesheds, as at work or where several apartments have one common shed or are these for each one family home?

The first document and image are targeted on public services, like bus and train stations, schools, event spaces. Wherever there is a large number of bikes to store and lock with different positions and orientations (angled, stacked, ...). The latter ist targeted on people, that plan and build homes with the bicycle in mind. This should include the everyday Joe, when he's thinking about building a bike shed.

Nice find. There's one very important thing, however, that's missing: They totally failed to account for baskets on the luggage racks. A bike that's not able to carry some stuff along with the rider is next to useless. Be it for commuting (carrying along spare cloths and/or rain gear) or for stocking up on food etc. If you take these into account properly, you definitely need more than 1m offset between double sided parking spots.

Absolutly! When you're planning for big bags, now is the time to consider them! From my personal experience I would say, that it's fine to store my bike in a quite small space and load/unload my bike in front of the designated parking lot. Typical bike bags are not wider than your handlebars or 30 cm per side.

For a family shed you can get more bikes in when needed, in the house I grew up in we had at least six bikes, they were stacked against the walls and each other and if you had to leave early you would move up to three bikes over to the other stack to get to yours.

I doubt, that OP is asking his question here to get answers like "just throw 'em in a pit". To maximise the bikes per square meter, there are options to stack them vertically. Google "double deck parker bicycle". With a little more roof height you gain doubled bikes/m²

@ultrakult When you are designing a bike shed, it's definitely not the time to be stingy with space. It's a pay once or suffer lifelong decision. If you've really overdimensioned, you will find uses for the space. But if you've underdimensioned, you are stuck with a dysfunctional shed.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica are baskets wider than the handlebars? I have a fairly large front basket on my commuter and it's not wider than the handlebars and doesn't stick out ahead of front tire. Also, do people leave their bags on racks? In my experience, people take the bags with them.

@PaulH No, it would be a big mistake to mount a basket that's wider than the handlebar. And a basket on the front is generally not a problem. But front baskets are rather limited in the amount of stuff you can carry with them, as they have no rigid support from below. That's what a luggage rack basket is for: decent capability of actually carrying stuff. And the problem with them is that they are on the other end of the bike, where they readily collide with the handlebars of bikes parked next to them in opposite direction. The last graphic in the answer shows what does not work (right side).

@cmaster-reinstatemonica. huh. I never though about putting a basket on the back. My front basket is mounted to a rack.

@PaulH Weird. The rear is definitely the better place for heavy loads as they don't interfere with steering there. I would hate to have a significant off-axis mass that needs to be flung around with every steering impulse I make; but I can have pretty much any load behind my butt without it negatively impacting the handling of the bike. As such, most bikes used to be equipped with a rear luggage rack by default, leaving the front wheel clear of any extra mass.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica I much prefer to have loads even on the heavy-ish side on the front, especially in an unpaved situation and front wheel traction is at a premium.
